# Inject user defined behavior in class

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently developing a php class and I intend to make it as reusable as possible, therefore I have to separate some of the logic from that class.
The solution I came up with is this.

```
myClass
{
    public function someHandler($function)
    {
        //some class dependent logic
            $function();
        //some other class dependent logic
    }
}
```

And then when the class is instantiated it goes like this:

```
$someRandomVar ='someValue';

$myClass = new myClass();
$myClass->someHandler(function() use ($someRandomVar, &$someRandomOutput) {
    //define some behavior which can also include $someRandomVar and $someRandomOutput
});

//$someRandomOutput will be used here somewhere
```

The logic from within the class is more complex than this but nobody will ever care about it, I'm just trying to make the class as user friendly as possible.

I know this might look like bad design but I have to do this somehow because some of the logic doesn't belong to that class but the class needs to execute that user defined code which I can't entirely separate from the class and this is where I come to my question: What is the best way to do this in terms of performance / overhead / user friendliness?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern. Outside users can attach observers to certain events that are called within your class. `$myClass->attachObserver('save', function() { ... }); $this->notifyObservers('save', $data);`

Comment: It looks like you're crossing OO delegations (like the Strategy Pattern) with the more functional concept of high order functions.  Neither are bad designs, though I'd try to remain consistent to one paradigm or the other unless you have a reason not to, particularly if you care about being developer friendly.  It's a fine approach in terms of the other concerns (performance/overhead) and would be premature optimization to care at this point.  With OO you'd probably get marginally better performance using the Template Pattern instead with more design time control but less runtime flexibility.

Comment: I think what the original poster wanted is something of a DECORATOR pattern, in which He can change the method to be executed from the calling client dynamically. Sort of Injecting a logic to be executed during runtime

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions, I've decided that using a higher order function instead of any design pattern will produce less overhead to the users of the class.